# Is it safe to allow CORS requests to a web api 2 webservice?

Tags: web-services, cors

I am coding a C# Web API 2 webservice that has CRUD actions for some DbSet objects. The RequestHeaders.Authorization has basic authentication.

I am wanting users to be able to access the webservice from their own javaScript code. This includes Get, Post, Put and Delete methods.

Am I correct in saying that CORS is required for this? Also, is there any reason why I should not use CORS with a Web API 2 webservice that has the authentication in the Authorization RequestHeader?

Answer (score 1):

If your users are running javascript code on a different domain than your API, then yes, it is a cross origin request and your API must be configured with CORS headers. This has no relation with Authorization header in the request. With or without, you must allow your users' domain or "*" to enable access to your API.

You can use either of these packages -

a) Frame.Cors - Simple JSON-based configuration manager (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Frame.Cors/)

b) Microsoft.AspNet.Cors

Comment: Can authorization headers still be used successfully with no problems in cross origin requests?

Comment: Yes, they can be used.